# Css how to convert letter to a design

Tags: html, css

in my html, i want to display numbers inside a round design something like below image 
is there any way to display an image instead of the letter, as seen in this image, i have inspected element and found "(" and ")" is used to display the design like below, I didnt find how did they do this.
[image]

**reference** http://tanzil.net/#20:116

Comment: I only see regular parenthesis (i.e. `(` ) - so it's could be a locale-specific setting

Comment: yeah, that s my question, nothing is found in css class

Answer (score 5):

These are ornate parenthesis (HTML entities [`&#64830;`](http://graphemica.com/%EF%B4%BE) and [`&#64831;`](http://graphemica.com/%EF%B4%BF)).

You can either type these manually in your text, or wrap your numbers in a specific tag (such as the `<i>`) to insert these automatically using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

```css
i { font-style: normal }
i::before {
  content:"﴾";
}
i::after {
  content:"﴿";
}
```

```html
<p>I have <i>99</i> problems</p>
```

Comment: you are correct, i just copied the letter and set font to arabic,

Comment: If this answer is correct, you must accept it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Eastern Arabic numbers are represented by Unicode ranging from HEX `0660` to `0669`

```
CHR  DEC     HEX

٠    1632    0660
١    1633    0661
٢    1634    0662
٣    1635    0663
٤    1636    0664
٥    1637    0665
٦    1638    0666
٧    1639    0667
٨    1640    0668
٩    1641    0669
```

The decorative characters are

```
﴾    64830   fd3e
﴿    64831   fd3f
```

You can use CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements passing the Unicode HEX as `content`

```css
body {direction: rtl;unicode-bidi: bidi-override;}

.num:before { content: "\fd3f"; }
.num:after  { content: "\fd3e"; }
```

```html
<span class="num">٤٩</span>
```

---

#### JavaScript

Having an element with text, if you want to **dynamically wrap** numbers into decorative braces, you can use `.replace()` and a bit of RegExp, which will replace any `0660` - `0669` range with that same number/s - wrapped by braces

```js
var text = "نَّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ سَيَجْعَلُ لَهُمُ الرَّحْمَـٰنُ وُدًّا ٩٦ فَإِنَّمَا يَسَّرْنَاهُ بِلِسَانِكَ لِتُبَشِّرَ بِهِ الْمُتَّقِينَ وَتُنذِرَ بِهِ قَوْمًا لُّدًّا ٩٧ وَكَمْ أَهْلَكْنَا قَبْلَهُم مِّن قَرْنٍ هَلْ تُحِسُّ مِنْهُم مِّنْ أَحَدٍ أَوْ تَسْمَعُ لَهُمْ رِكْزًا ٩";

var niceNum = text.replace(/([\u0660-\u0669]+)/g, "\ufd3f$1\ufd3e");

console.log( niceNum )
```

```css
body {direction: rtl;unicode-bidi: bidi-override;}
```

If `"\ufd3f$1\ufd3e"` seems quite cryptic, those are nothing but Unicode `\u` HEX for braces `fd3f` `fd3e`, where `$1` is the retrieved **matching numbers range** `([\u0660-\u0669]+)`.

---

Now that you learned you can use the prefix `\u` in **CSS** and **JavaScript** to indicate that the following characters represent a **Unicode HEX *number***,
 you can do the same in **HTML** by using the `&#x` prefix:

﴾ `&#xfd3e;`
﴿ `&#xfd3f;`

or even using the numerical character code prefixed by `&#`:

﴾ `&#64830;`
﴿ `&#64831;`

or by using the ﴾ ﴿ characters right away given `<meta charset="utf-8">` in `head` of your document - and the host browser supports that UTF range.

---

Now that you understand the above, for future reference, if you have a *special* character like ﴾ and want to quickly get it's numeric **Decimal** or **HEX** value, all you have to do is to bring up your Developer Console and write:

```
"﴾".charCodeAt(0)                 // 64830         <<< Numeric Decimal value
```

or

```
"﴾".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)    // "fd3e"        <<< HEX value
```

Comment: this is helpful. thanks

Comment: @rashidnk you're welcome